# Is there a way to make a restore point in a WebView app?

Tags: java, android, webview

I need help with my application, made in android studio. I have most basic start of the code.. but nothing i have tried get me to a restore point when i close the app. I wanted to know how to do that.

I have tried to restore save points, hold in-app cache, etc. but nothing works for some reason. The site i am loading in is an HTML5 Canvas flash game.

My MainActivity.java:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // WebView Variable
    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Call on ID
        mWebView = findViewById(R.id.webviewid);

        // Load Javascript
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        // Remote URL
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://www.coolmathgames.com/0-idle-breakout/play");
        mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);

    }
}
```

My Androidmanifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.port.idlebreakout">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And my activity_main.xml:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webviewid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></WebView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your activity blog in Androidmanifest
**Add this tow lines:**

```
    android:launchMode="singleInstance"
    android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
```

In Androidmanifes:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
    android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Happy Learning...